# Help provign that $\mathbb{N}$ is dense in topology space and investigating whether topology is separable.

Tags: general-topology

So i have $\mathcal{T}$ defined as finite complement topology on $\mathbb{R}$

So i have to prove that $\mathbb{N}$ is dense on $\mathbb{R}$.

And also i have to investigate before mentioned topology for being separable.

So my initial idea is that since  $\mathbb{N}$ is a countably infinite set any open set in ($\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T})$ will intersect the set of naturals. That means it's dense everywhere for this topology.This actually proves that its dense and that the $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal)$ is separable.

Is this the correct way, or did i miss something.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof seems to be correct. Here's another, more general approach:

In finite complement topology a subset $F\subseteq X$ is closed if and only if $F$ is either finite or whole $X$.

So now consider an infinite subset $A\subseteq X$. Since $A\subseteq \overline{A}$ then $\overline{A}$ is infinite and since $\overline{A}$ is closed then $\overline{A}=X$. In particular every infinite subset of $X$ is dense.

So $X$ is always separable because it is either finite or it has a countable subset which I proved to be dense.

Comment: Hence this proves that $\mathbb{N}$ is dense and $X$ is separable. 
That is much more general.